# JSON - display values and adding new one line

Tags: javascript, json

How to display "name" value for id 12?And how to add another new user for timeless json (without saving .json file) and display final result?

```
var json = {
    "users": [
        {"id": 322, "name": "Ivan"},
        {"id": 12, "name": "Vanya"}
    ]
};

var str = JSON.stringify(json);

console.log(str.users.name); // ??
```

Comment: JSON.parse() should be used.. not stringify

Comment: can you explain what "timeless json" is? is that json file you are currently working with?

Comment: I want to clarify some terms. **JSON** is a _“data-interchange language”_ **it’s only actually JSON when it’s used in a string context**. The variable `json` actually is a **Object Literal**. The method `JSON.stringify(json)` converts the Object Literal into a JSON string. @RahulB added the answer you need. And one last thing, worth to read the following article: ***[There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display name with any particular id-

```
for(var i in json.users){
    if(json.users[i].id==12)
        console.log(json.users[i].name);
}
```

To add new obj-

```
var newobj={"id" : 3, "name": "MyName"};
json.users.push(newobj);
console.log(json.users);
```

Demo- http://jsfiddle.net/m0hxfs66/

Check output in console

Answer (score 0):

```
var str=JSON.parse(json);
console.log(str.users[0].name); //Ivan will be output
```

Comment: this is not returning the result for id=12 as requested

Comment: Thank you, but how to display name for specific id?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` is a function that takes a value and returns its JSON equivalent, which is a string.  You're `json` variable is a javascript object, not a JSON string.  If you want to add another user you would just use something like json["users"].push({ id:44, name: "Antoni"});  Then you can convert to a JSON string for storage with `JSON.stringingfy()` or convert back with `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
var json = {
    "users": [
        {"id": 322, "name": "Ivan"},
        {"id": 12, "name": "Vanya"}
    ]
};

//To print name value of id 12
for (var 1=0; i< json.users.length; i+=1){
    if(json.users[i].id===12){
      console.log(json.users[i].name); //Prints name value of user id 12
      break;
    }
}

//To Add new user
json.users.push({"id": 143, "name": "Adam"})
```